# How to declare type alias in generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```js
type T<T> = { [index in keyof T & string]: keyof T & string }

type T2<T, K extends string = keyof T & string> = { [index in K]: K }
```

`keyof T & string` appears twice in `T`. In a more complex type generic, it could be verbose.

In `T2`, generic paramater `K` has a default value `keyof T & string`, but `K` is acceptable. Is there a way to make type alias in generic type body or make `K` unacceptable?

Comment: Sometimes I use conditional type inference to copy a type into a new type parameter, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqE5rm), but I don't know if that approach is desired here.

Comment: @jcalz That works well but it has a complex syntax and more performance cost.

Comment: What are you basing "more performance cost" on, here?  Is that just your opinion or do you have some evidence of this?

Comment: Just my opinion. Would typescript do more work on conditional type analysis? @jcalz

Comment: Just use appropriate constraint like [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBjkxN).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to define a type alias within the body of the other type declaration, however, you could define a type alias for the duplicated sub-expression in your main type alias:

```
type S<T> = keyof T & string

type T<T> = { [index in S<T>]: S<T> }
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygPAFQHxQLxQNYRAewGZQJQBkUAzsAE4CWAdgOYBQjokhiK6A3lANp0ATCAA8odWBwC6ALgnIoAX0ZA

Comment: Better but not perfect :)